# A question dealing with the convexity of functions involving the absolute value

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Just beginning to learn convex analysis and optimization, I have some inquiries to make with regard to the absolute value function $f(x)= |x|$. This function is clearly convex, but since we know that $|x|= \max\{x,-x\}$, does this make $\max$ a convex function? How about $\min$? My guess is that the minimum function is concave, but I might be wrong. I'd appreciate any helpful input on these questions I'm having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimisation result is that the [pointwise supremum of affine functions](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mYm0bLd3fcoC&pg=PA80&dq=maximum+linear+convex&hl=en&sa=X&ei=m8MiUcHBLbCV0QWRk4HwAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=pointwise%20supremum%20of%20affine&f=false) is convex. On the contrary, the pointwise infimum of linear (or affine) functions is concave.

$\max\{x,-x\}$ is convex because it is the maximum of two linear functions of $x$, namely $x$ and $-x$.

Comment: What about $ \max_{i} x - \min_{i} x $? Namely the difference between the maximum and minimum component of a vector?

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the maximum, and you could find this fact in [Wikipedia: properties of convex functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Convex_function_calculus).

Also right about the minimum being concave. Remember that everything we say about convex functions translates into statements about concave functions simply by replacing $f$ with $-f$. This also switches $\max$ and $\min$ around.

Comment: So $\min$ is never convex?

Comment: @Sachin Depends on $\min$ of what you take. For example, $\min(e^x,1+x)$ is convex.